# awk in script to copy data to a file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have copied some columns data to some file and then tried to write one column data to another file. But am getting few wrong

This is my input file:-

```
,E2Bn9,2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500

['2C173'],E2BA8,2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500

['5A475','2C174'],E2BA8,2015-06-29 00:00:00-0400
```

I used the `awk`, `sed` commands as follows

```
sed -i 's/",/|/g' tempFile
awk -F '[|,]' '{ print "update table set cola = " $1 " where colb = " $2 " and colc = " $3 }' tempFile > updatestmt.cql
```

I got the output as

```
update table set cola = where colb = E2Bn9 and colc = 2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500

update table set cola = ['2C173'] where colb = E2BA8 and colc = 2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500

update table set cola = "['5A475' where colb =  '2C174'] and colc = E2BA8
```

1st two rows seems fine but last row it is printing wrong value.

I want the last row as

```
update table set cola = "['5A475','2C174'] where colb =E2BA8 and colc = 2015-06-29 00:00:00-0400
```

Comment: Problem with the last row seems the comma inside the brackets. It mix up the field numbering when splitted at commas. Give me a few minutes to come up with some alternative for the first sed...

Comment: What is the purpose of the `sed` command before the awk one? It would not change anything in your posted sample input. If you need it then include the use case for it in your sample input. If you don't need it then get rid of it.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk 4.* for `FPAT`:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|([[][^]]+[]])' '{print "update table set cola =", $1, "where colb =", $2, "and colc =", $3}' file
update table set cola =  where colb = E2Bn9 and colc = 2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500
update table set cola = ['2C173'] where colb = E2BA8 and colc = 2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500
update table set cola = ['5A475','2C174'] where colb = E2BA8 and colc = 2015-06-29 00:00:00-0400
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content.

With non-gawk awks or pre-4.0 versions of gawk (get a modern gawk!) you can use:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    delete f
    nf = 0
    tail = $0
    while ( (tail!="") && match(tail,/([^,]*)|([[][^]]+[]])/) ) {
        f[++nf] = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
    }
    print "update table set cola =", f[1], "where colb =", f[2], "and colc =", f[3]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
update table set cola =  where colb = E2Bn9 and colc = 2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500
update table set cola = ['2C173'] where colb = E2BA8 and colc = 2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500
update table set cola = ['5A475','2C174'] where colb = E2BA8 and colc = 2015-06-29 00:00:00-0400
```

You can use `$0` instead of `f[]` but then there's a performance overhead as the record gets re-split every time you assign to `$(++nf)` and there may be cases where you want to use the original `$0` later.

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for replying i tried with FPAT
but still gets same output as i was getting previously-
['A01WWSS2', where colb = 'A1EEE']",P19S2,2015-12-15 and colc = 12:00:00-0500

Comment: That is a prehistoric version of gawk lacking a ton of extremely useful features, including FPAT (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History). I added a script that will work in that and other awks but you really need to get a new version of gawk.

Answer (score 1):

I chose a different approach,
so I could avoid using too complex reg-exp
and it works with any old awk.

```
# cat tst.awk
        {s="";}
$1!=""  {for(i=1;i<NF-1;i++)s=s (i==1?"":",") $i;}
        {printf("update table set cola = %s where colb = %s and colc = %s\n",s,$(NF-1),$NF);}

# awk -F, -f tst.awk yourinpfile
update table set cola =  where colb = E2Bn9 and colc = 2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500
update table set cola = ['2C173'] where colb = E2BA8 and colc = 2015-04-29 00:00:00-0500
update table set cola = ['5A475','2C174'] where colb = E2BA8 and colc = 2015-06-29 00:00:00-0400
```

I agree with Ed that without loop we have a nicer solution, but I can reuse my original assumption that `$(NF-1)` and `$NF` is fix, to keep the simpler reg-exp.

```
        {s="";}
$1!=""  {s=$0;sub("," $(NF-1) "," $NF, "", s);}
        {printf("update table set cola = %s where colb = %s and colc = %s\n",s,$(NF-1),$NF);}
```

Comment: That is actually a good idea (assuming the first field is the only problematic field), but it can be done without the loop: `cola=$0; sub(/(,[^,]+){2}$/,"",cola); print "cola=", cola, "colb=", $(NF-1), "colc=", $NF`.

Answer (score 0):

The field separators in your data are causing the problems, to be precise the comma inside the brackets in the third line. A workaround could be a different sed that only converts `,` to `|` outside of the first bracket and using `FS='|'`:

```
sed -r 's/(.*\])?.*,/\1|/g'  yourfile | awk -F '|' ....
```

where `....` stand for the rest of your awk script.

Comment: Hi Lars, i tried with this script but output file remains empty. Its not writing anything to o/p file

Comment: @user5655807 I think you need a command like this: `sed -r 's/(.*\])?.*,/\1|/g' tempFile | awk -F '|' '{ print "update table set cola = " $1 " where colb = " $2 " and colc = " $3 }'  > updatestmt.cql`.  
Here `tempfile` is the input. sed creates output on *stdout* and **pipes** it directly into awk. awk writes on stdout, which is redirected into  `updatestmt.cql`.

Answer (score 0):

If only list values are quoted as in your sample code, you can try this sed ;

```
sed "s/' *, *'/' '/g;s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/update table set cola = \1 where colb = \2 and colc = \3/;s/' '/','/g" file
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.. thank you all for your help and suggestion. Appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome. You may accept the answer if it helped.